# Fullcalendar not showing events in IOS devices

Tags: ios, fullcalendar

I have used Fullcalendar in one of my html page. It is working fine in chrome and mozilla. Also same is working fine in Android devices. But issue is with IOS device.

Calendar events itself are not being loaded. Didn't found any solution for this on net. Please provide any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple of attempts:

- try to load another url and to see if the problem is in your html page or in your app
- take a look at your plist, in particular at the `NSAppTransportSecurity`

In this second case, you can add this key:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

If the problem is the `NSAppTransportSecurity`, you'll have to set up it correctly with your domain.

Comment: Hi Zeb, Other pages are working fine seems there may be something else is wrong.

Comment: Are you using a webview inside your app or what?

Comment: @Zeb- No I am not using webview.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get this deprecation warning in browser console?

> Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized ISO format.
>   moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable
>   across all browsers and versions. Non ISO date formats are discouraged
>   and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to
>   http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.

If yes, check the date format for event start and end. 
In my app it was RFC822 (nonISO), causing fallback to date format not working on iOS devices.

Changing date parsing to **ISO8601** helped in my case.