# Fullcalendar not showing events in IOS devices ( < iOS 12)

Tags: javascript, iphone, safari, fullcalendar

I have used Fullcalendar in one of my Wordpress page. It is working fine in Chrome and Mozilla. Also the same is working fine in Android devices. But issue is with IOS device. (It works on iOS >=12)

Calendar events it self-are not being loaded. Didn't find any solution for this on net. Please provide any help on this.

Link events calendar: https://livemusicnow-koeln.de/konzertkalender/

I also tried to follow the answer to the below question but doesn't work. ([Fullcalendar not showing events in IOS devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40280577/fullcalendar-not-showing-events-in-ios-devices))

Answer (score 0):

Visiting the site you linked to, at the time of writing this answer the events do not show up in any browser. It doesn't appear to be restricted to iOS devices (or any other browser or operating system).

This is because there's a mistake in the code. You've defined your event start dates like this:

```
start: console.log(moment('2018-11-14', moment.ISO_8601))
```

but this makes no sense. You're telling the code to return the result of the `console.log()` command and use that as the start date. But `console.log()` does not return any data, it just logs things to the debug console (here's a demo which shows that it doesn't return anything: http://jsfiddle.net/q4zabdrf/)

You can just define you dates very simply like this:

```
start: "2018-11-14"
```

fullCalendar will read the string and parse it as a momentJS object itself, and then your events should display correctly. (Since its in a valid ISO8601 format, it will successfully read it automatically without being told what format to expect).

Comment: Hi @adyson,
I forgot disabled console.log after test yesterday.
Currently, I have set time format as you said, but it still doesn't work on iPhone. Can you have any other way?

Comment: I have created the issue topic here. Can you help me? https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/4322

Comment: have you tried executing in some sandbox environment such as browserstack or something then you can maybe monitor things like console errors which might be occurring in the browser? Also what version of iOS? That will tell us the version of Safari, and that might potentially be significant.